# App crashing on Windows Phone when deployed in Release mode

Tags: crash, windows-phone, xamarin.forms, release-mode

We have developed a Xamarin Forms app supporting Android, iOS and Windows Phone. The app is working on all three OSes when deployed in Debug mode.

It's also working on Android and iOS when deployed in Release mode. It crashes immediately after displaying Splash screen on Windows Phone 8.1/10 when deployed with Release mode, but strangely all works fine when deployed using Debug mode.

What is the reason?

Is there a way to get see the app log to diagnose the crash reason?

**EDIT 1:**
Hi Gerald/Demitrian,

Thanks a lot for your response. Please find below the contents for Output window. There is a XamlParseException but no additional information. I have also attached the debug log from "Decuments\Debug" folder of a Windows Phone.

**Contents from output window:**

```
'AgHost.exe' (CoreCLR: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\mscorlib.ni.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'AgHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Windows.RuntimeHost.ni.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'AgHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Windows.ni.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'AgHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Net.ni.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'AgHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.ni.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'AgHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Xml.ni.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'AgHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\data\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\AppRepository\Packages\MultiEventsApp_1.0.0.0_neutral__74wf2z3scmpey\NI\MultiEventsApp.WinPhone.ni.DLL'. Symbols loaded.
'AgHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\Microsoft.Phone.ni.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'AgHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\data\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\AppRepository\Packages\MultiEventsApp_1.0.0.0_neutral__74wf2z3scmpey\NI\MultiEventsApp.ni.DLL'. Symbols loaded.
'AgHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\data\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\AppRepository\Packages\MultiEventsApp_1.0.0.0_neutral__74wf2z3scmpey\NI\Parse.ni.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'AgHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\data\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\AppRepository\Packages\MultiEventsApp_1.0.0.0_neutral__74wf2z3scmpey\NI\Parse.Phone.ni.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'AgHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\data\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\AppRepository\Packages\MultiEventsApp_1.0.0.0_neutral__74wf2z3scmpey\NI\Xamarin.Forms.Core.ni.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'AgHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Runtime.ni.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'AgHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Threading.Tasks.ni.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'AgHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\Microsoft.Phone.Interop.ni.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'AgHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Core.ni.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'AgHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\WinMetadata\Windows.winmd'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentNullException' in mscorlib.ni.dll
'AgHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\data\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\AppRepository\Packages\MultiEventsApp_1.0.0.0_neutral__74wf2z3scmpey\NI\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.WP8.ni.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'AgHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\data\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\AppRepository\Packages\MultiEventsApp_1.0.0.0_neutral__74wf2z3scmpey\NI\ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms.WindowsPhone.ni.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'AgHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\data\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\AppRepository\Packages\MultiEventsApp_1.0.0.0_neutral__74wf2z3scmpey\NI\ImageCircle.Forms.Plugin.WindowsPhone.ni.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'AgHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\data\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\AppRepository\Packages\MultiEventsApp_1.0.0.0_neutral__74wf2z3scmpey\NI\Xamarin.Forms.Maps.WP8.ni.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'AgHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\data\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\AppRepository\Packages\MultiEventsApp_1.0.0.0_neutral__74wf2z3scmpey\NI\ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms.ni.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'AgHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\data\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\AppRepository\Packages\MultiEventsApp_1.0.0.0_neutral__74wf2z3scmpey\NI\ZXingNetMobile.ni.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'AgHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\data\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\AppRepository\Packages\MultiEventsApp_1.0.0.0_neutral__74wf2z3scmpey\NI\ZXing.Net.Mobile.Core.ni.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'AgHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\data\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\AppRepository\Packages\MultiEventsApp_1.0.0.0_neutral__74wf2z3scmpey\NI\System.Windows.Interactivity.ni.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'AgHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\data\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\AppRepository\Packages\MultiEventsApp_1.0.0.0_neutral__74wf2z3scmpey\NI\microsoft.phone.controls.toolkit.ni.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'AgHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Collections.ni.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'AgHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Resources.ResourceManager.ni.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'AgHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\data\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\AppRepository\Packages\MultiEventsApp_1.0.0.0_neutral__74wf2z3scmpey\NI\ImageCircle.Forms.Plugin.Abstractions.ni.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'AgHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\data\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\AppRepository\Packages\MultiEventsApp_1.0.0.0_neutral__74wf2z3scmpey\NI\Xamarin.Forms.Maps.ni.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'AgHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\Microsoft.Phone.Maps.ni.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'AgHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Runtime.Serialization.ni.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'AgHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\data\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\AppRepository\Packages\MultiEventsApp_1.0.0.0_neutral__74wf2z3scmpey\NI\Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.ni.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'AgHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Diagnostics.Debug.ni.dll'. Symbols loaded.
Exception thrown: 'Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseException' in Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.ni.DLL
Exception thrown: 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' in mscorlib.ni.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' in Microsoft.Phone.ni.dll
```

**Contents from Documents\Debug folder:**

```
Dump Summary
------------
Dump File:  MultiEventsApp with exception E0434352 on 1-07-2017 17.55.dmp : C:\Users\Pocket_User\Desktop\MultiEventsApp with exception E0434352 on 1-07-2017 17.55.dmp
Last Write Time:    1/7/2017 5:55:50 PM
Process Name:   aghost.exe : aghost.exe
Process Architecture:   ARM
Exception Code: 0xE0434352
Exception Information:  
Heap Information:   Present

System Information
------------------
OS Version: 10.0.14393
CLR Version(s): 4.5.22926.0

Modules
-------
Module Name Module Path Module Version
----------- ----------- --------------
aghost.exe  aghost.exe  10.0.14393.576
ntdll.dll   ntdll.dll   10.0.14393.576
KERNELBASE.dll  KERNELBASE.dll  10.0.14393.576
combase.dll combase.dll 10.0.14393.576
ucrtbase.dll    ucrtbase.dll    10.0.14393.576
RPCRT4.dll  RPCRT4.dll  10.0.14393.576
kernel32legacy.dll  kernel32legacy.dll  10.0.14393.576
bcryptPrimitives.dll    bcryptPrimitives.dll    10.0.14393.576
msvcrt.dll  msvcrt.dll  7.0.14393.576
kernel.appcore.dll  kernel.appcore.dll  10.0.14393.576
OLEAUT32.dll    OLEAUT32.dll    10.0.14393.576
shcore.dll  shcore.dll  10.0.14393.576
AgHostSvcs.dll  AgHostSvcs.dll  10.0.14393.576
TaskHostCore.dll    TaskHostCore.dll    10.0.14393.576
msvcp_win.dll   msvcp_win.dll   10.0.14393.576
wintypes.dll    wintypes.dll    10.0.14393.576
OnDemandBrokerClient.dll    OnDemandBrokerClient.dll    10.0.14393.576
advapi32legacy.dll  advapi32legacy.dll  10.0.14393.576
sechost.dll sechost.dll 10.0.14393.576
CoreUIComponents.dll    CoreUIComponents.dll    0.0.0.0
CoreMessaging.dll   CoreMessaging.dll   10.0.14393.576
EMCLIENT.dll    EMCLIENT.dll    10.0.14393.576
TASKHOSTSVCS.dll    TASKHOSTSVCS.dll    10.0.14393.576
WpPortingLibrary.dll    WpPortingLibrary.dll    0.0.0.0
SspiCli.dll SspiCli.dll 10.0.14393.576
minuser.dll minuser.dll 0.0.0.0
win32u.dll  win32u.dll  10.0.14393.576
gdi32.dll   gdi32.dll   10.0.14393.576
modernapiexthost.dll    modernapiexthost.dll    0.0.0.0
SecRuntime.dll  SecRuntime.dll  0.0.0.0
gdi32min.dll    gdi32min.dll    10.0.14393.576
WpCoreUtil.DLL  WpCoreUtil.DLL  0.0.0.0
msvcp110_win.dll    msvcp110_win.dll    10.0.14393.576
storageusage.dll    storageusage.dll    10.0.14393.576
procthreadexthost.dll   procthreadexthost.dll   0.0.0.0
ntmarta.dll ntmarta.dll 10.0.14393.576
CoreApplicationShim.dll CoreApplicationShim.dll 0.0.0.0
twinapi.appcore.dll twinapi.appcore.dll 10.0.14393.576
bcrypt.dll  bcrypt.dll  10.0.14393.576
PsmApp.dll  PsmApp.dll  10.0.14393.576
AppModelProxy.dll   AppModelProxy.dll   0.0.0.0
pacmantileshim.dll  pacmantileshim.dll  10.0.14393.576
VEEventDispatcher.dll   VEEventDispatcher.dll   10.0.14393.576
ActXPrxy.dll    ActXPrxy.dll    10.0.14393.576
pacmanclient.dll    pacmanclient.dll    10.0.14393.576
RMClient.dll    RMClient.dll    10.0.14393.576
mrmcorer.dll    mrmcorer.dll    10.0.14393.576
windows.ui.dll  windows.ui.dll  10.0.14393.576
dcomp.dll   dcomp.dll   10.0.14393.576
inputhost.dll   inputhost.dll   0.0.0.0
textinputframework.dll  textinputframework.dll  10.0.14393.576
CRYPTBASE.dll   CRYPTBASE.dll   10.0.14393.576
npctrl.dll  npctrl.dll  0.0.0.0
PROPSYS.dll PROPSYS.dll 7.0.14393.576
agcore.dll  agcore.dll  4.1.60221.0
SL_InterprocDll.dll SL_InterprocDll.dll 0.0.0.0
WS2_32.dll  WS2_32.dll  10.0.14393.576
CRYPT32.dll CRYPT32.dll 10.0.14393.576
d3d11.dll   d3d11.dll   10.0.14393.576
WININET.dll WININET.dll 11.0.14393.576
ole32_wp.dll    ole32_wp.dll    10.0.14393.576
urlmon.dll  urlmon.dll  11.0.14393.576
PlatformInterop.dll PlatformInterop.dll 0.0.0.0
MSASN1.dll  MSASN1.dll  10.0.14393.576
dxgi.dll    dxgi.dll    10.0.14393.576
iertutil.dll    iertutil.dll    11.0.14393.576
shlwapi.dll shlwapi.dll 10.0.14393.576
cfgmgr32.dll    cfgmgr32.dll    10.0.14393.576
dsclient.dll    dsclient.dll    10.0.14393.576
Windows.Storage.dll Windows.Storage.dll 10.0.14393.576
powrprof.dll    powrprof.dll    10.0.14393.576
profapi.dll profapi.dll 10.0.14393.576
coreclr.dll coreclr.dll 4.5.22926.0
CRYPTSP.dll CRYPTSP.dll 10.0.14393.576
werapiexthost.dll   werapiexthost.dll   0.0.0.0
mscorlib.ni.dll mscorlib.ni.dll 4.5.22926.0
rsaenh.dll  rsaenh.dll  10.0.14393.576
System.Windows.RuntimeHost.ni.dll   System.Windows.RuntimeHost.ni.dll   2.0.6.0
System.Windows.ni.dll   System.Windows.ni.dll   4.7.50915.0
System.Net.ni.dll   System.Net.ni.dll   4.7.50915.0
System.ni.dll   System.ni.dll   4.5.22926.0
System.Xml.ni.dll   System.Xml.ni.dll   4.5.22926.0
appchromeapi.dll    appchromeapi.dll    0.0.0.0
qcdx11um8612.dll    qcdx11um8612.dll    9.18.2074.0
MSVCR120.dll    MSVCR120.dll    12.0.21005.1
qcdx11compiler8612.dll  qcdx11compiler8612.dll  1.0.2074.0
MSVCP120.dll    MSVCP120.dll    12.0.21005.1
ShellChromeAPI.dll  ShellChromeAPI.dll  0.0.0.0
MultiEventsApp.WinPhone.ni.DLL  MultiEventsApp.WinPhone.ni.DLL  1.0.0.0
Microsoft.Phone.ni.dll  Microsoft.Phone.ni.dll  0.0.0.0
MultiEventsApp.ni.DLL   MultiEventsApp.ni.DLL   1.0.0.0
Parse.ni.DLL    Parse.ni.DLL    1.7.0.0
Parse.Phone.ni.DLL  Parse.Phone.ni.DLL  1.7.0.0
Xamarin.Forms.Core.ni.DLL   Xamarin.Forms.Core.ni.DLL   2.0.0.0
System.Runtime.ni.dll   System.Runtime.ni.dll   4.5.22926.0
System.Threading.Tasks.ni.dll   System.Threading.Tasks.ni.dll   4.5.22926.0
Microsoft.Phone.Interop.ni.dll  Microsoft.Phone.Interop.ni.dll  0.0.0.0
phoneinfo.dll   phoneinfo.dll   0.0.0.0
System.Core.ni.dll  System.Core.ni.dll  4.5.22926.0
wpnapps.dll wpnapps.dll 10.0.14393.576
XmlLite.dll XmlLite.dll 10.0.14393.576
Windows.ni.winmd    Windows.ni.winmd    0.0.0.0
Windows.winmd   Windows.winmd   0.0.0.0
StorageProxy.dll    StorageProxy.dll    0.0.0.0
Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.dll Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.dll 10.0.14393.576
YPerfHealthLogger.dll   YPerfHealthLogger.dll   0.0.0.0
dwrite.dll  dwrite.dll  10.0.14393.576
Xamarin.Forms.Platform.WP8.ni.DLL   Xamarin.Forms.Platform.WP8.ni.DLL   2.0.0.0
ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms.WindowsPhone.ni.DLL  ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms.WindowsPhone.ni.DLL  2.1.47.0
ImageCircle.Forms.Plugin.WindowsPhone.ni.DLL    ImageCircle.Forms.Plugin.WindowsPhone.ni.DLL    1.8.1.8
Xamarin.Forms.Maps.WP8.ni.DLL   Xamarin.Forms.Maps.WP8.ni.DLL   2.0.0.0
ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms.ni.DLL   ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms.ni.DLL   2.1.47.0
ZXingNetMobile.ni.DLL   ZXingNetMobile.ni.DLL   2.1.47.0
ZXing.Net.Mobile.Core.ni.DLL    ZXing.Net.Mobile.Core.ni.DLL    2.1.47.0
System.Windows.Interactivity.ni.DLL System.Windows.Interactivity.ni.DLL 3.0.30924.0
microsoft.phone.controls.toolkit.ni.DLL microsoft.phone.controls.toolkit.ni.DLL 8.0.1.0
System.Collections.ni.dll   System.Collections.ni.dll   4.5.22926.0
System.Resources.ResourceManager.ni.dll System.Resources.ResourceManager.ni.dll 4.5.22926.0
ImageCircle.Forms.Plugin.Abstractions.ni.DLL    ImageCircle.Forms.Plugin.Abstractions.ni.DLL    1.8.1.8
Xamarin.Forms.Maps.ni.DLL   Xamarin.Forms.Maps.ni.DLL   2.0.0.0
Microsoft.Phone.Maps.ni.dll Microsoft.Phone.Maps.ni.dll 3.0.30701.2350
System.Runtime.Serialization.ni.dll System.Runtime.Serialization.ni.dll 4.5.22926.0
Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.ni.DLL   Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.ni.DLL   2.0.0.0
System.Diagnostics.Debug.ni.dll System.Diagnostics.Debug.ni.dll 4.5.22926.0
errorhandlingext.dll    errorhandlingext.dll    10.0.10011.16384
mintdh.dll  mintdh.dll  10.0.14393.576
```

**EDIT 2:**
I made some progress on this issue. FontFamily property was causing issue in my case. So if remove the fontfamily property and run the app in Release mode, exception is not thrown anymore but the way the screen is rendered on the device doesn't look like in any way the it's rendered in Debug mode.

I have attached both the screen shots. I tried adding second option in Forms.Init as told by John but it's giving me error as the method doesn't support second option.

[Debug mode screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYwxe.png)

[Release mode screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgQtV.png)

On above behavior, I have following questions:

- Why the app is correctly working in Debug mode and not in Release
  mode?
- Why the screen renders correctly in Debug mode and not in
  Release mode?
- Why it doesn't throw any error the way it throws in
  Release mode?
- Is there any missing reference? Not sure if this is the case as the app would have thrown an exception saying so.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you already check the Output window?

Comment: As the question is currently written, it is difficult to assist you due to missing information. As mentioned [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/get-started/enable-your-device-for-development), you can find the dumps in your phone's storage in the Documents\Debug folder. Please attach the contents of the dump to your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, my problem is resolved. Please find the solution below if you have the same problem.

A step by step re-creation of the project revealed that my app was working fine until I added Xamarin.Forms.Maps package in my app. I was installing the latest version of Maps package which was upgrading it's dependant packages  to a higher version. Maps plugin caused Xamarin.Forms package to upgrade from 2.3.2.127 to 2.3.3.180. So when I was deploying the app with this version of Xamarin Forms in release mode, it was causing the app crashing and UI issues mentioned in my earlier response above.

To resolve the problem, I fall back to a lover version of Maps which was compatible with 2.3.2.127 version of Xamarin Forms and voila!

Looks like there is a bug in 2.3.3.180 version of Xamarin Forms.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of quick notes:

1.- Looks like the Register button is taking all the screen Height, have you tried to specify a Height for this button? Something like:

```
Button.HeightRequest = "40";
```

2.- Have you tried Linking behavior "Don't link"?

[image]